# Mac OSX Security tool without GUI prompt

Tags: macos, security, macos-high-sierra

I want to make an automation for one of my processes, but security cli always prompt with GUI admin password.

Can I make it on the terminal level?

Thanks
Jen

EDIT:

I mean - by going to the console and typing:

`security find-generic-password  -ws iCloud`

I am prompt with GUI of Admin password. I want to put the password through the Command line interface.